# Measurability preserving operators on $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu; \mathbb R^n)$, a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} \leq \mathcal{F}$, a function $f \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu; \mathbb R^n)$ which is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and a mapping $T: L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu; \mathbb R^n) \to L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu; \mathbb R^n)$.

Under which conditions on $T$ is $T(f)$ again $\mathcal{G}$-measurable? Is continuity enough? Linearity?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own, before coming to us?

Comment: Linearity **and** continuity together will not be enough in general. You will need to specify some more specific conditions.

Comment: @Robin Goodfellow: I tried but, unfortunately, could not get anywhere. I also looked up several measure theory books for hints, but did not find results that go in this direction.

I tried an example, where T is a orthogonal projection on a linear subspace, but for this special case the result seems to be wrong.